# URL PathVariable changes for one variable with 500 error, and not for another one

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm facing a puzzling issue with Spring boot that I can't understand why it's happening.

I have the following controller method

```
@GetMapping(value = { "/property/{address}" })
public String property(Model model, @PathVariable("address") String address, HttpServletRequest request) {
    System.out.println("Address: " + address);

    return "test";
}
```

The puzzling thing is that if I go to the following URL

```
http://localhost:8080/property/1081-Rbl-Estate-Rd-Pine-Bluff-AR-71603
```

I get a 500 error when I check the Google chrome http calls and the following gets printed

`Address: 1081-Rbl-Estate-Rd`

and the URL changes

`http://localhost:8080/property/1081-Rbl-Estate-Rd`

but if I go to

`http://localhost:8080/property/1100-Rbl-Estate-Rd-Pine-Bluff-AR-71603`

then the correct address gets printed, and the URL is also correct

`Address: 1100-Rbl-Estate-Rd-Pine-Bluff-AR-71603`

Somehow `-Rd-Pine-Bluff-AR-71603` is being stripped from the address on the first example, but not for the second one. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Very weird behaviour... After coding this over here and testing myself, it all worked just fine. Do you have a stacktrace to show more details on the error?

Comment: @DavidKrenkel looks like it has to do with some cache on Google Chrome. I just tried it on Firefox and this does not happen.

Comment: @DavidKrenkel it was something related to Chrome's cache. I cleared the cache and everything is good now